# validate + listener + slide down panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-effects

We have two form elements, only.
They are for numbers. If numebrs match ( using validate ) then I want a slide panel ( div ) to open.

No anchors buttons or links.

The issues I find, are triggering the panel to slide down, upon success of the second field match. I dont want the user to click away from the second input field, rather listen for event match, is success then div is revealed.

If they dont match or user changes the inputs the div closes.

...................
So here is some code.

```
<input id="mobile1" name="mobile1">
<input id="mobile2" name="mobile2">
```

Validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            mobile1: "required",
            mobile2: {
                equalTo: "#mobile1"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Slider , well seems to be a multitude of different versions we can use, toggle and slide both by jQuery spring to mind.

My issue is I want the event listener to trigger the slider panel, from the 2nd input field. Without user having to click anything anywhere else.

So as they enter 2nd input field.. soon as it matches, "live" the slider opens.

Any help appreciated.

Ok with Davids Help, this is what I have so far:

Validation:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#bugmeform").validate({
        rules: {
            mobile1: "required",
            mobile2: {
                equalTo: "#mobile1"
            }
        }
    });
});
```

jQuery Handler code mention below

```
$("#mobile2").bind('keyup', "paste", function () {
    if ($("#mobile1").val() == $("#mobile2").val()) {
        $("#slider").animate({
            width: "70%",
            opacity: 0.4,
            marginLeft: "0.6in",
            fontSize: "3em",
            borderWidth: "10px"
        }, 1500);
    });
```

Form Element looks like:
Mobile 1

```
<input id="mobile1" name="mobile1" class="small" size="12" type="text" onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey
                || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false)
                || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
                || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9)
                || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40)
                || (event.keyCode==46) )"
                class="medium"  onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false)" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.mobile1,this.form,10);"
```

onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.mobile1,this.form,10);" maxlength="10"/>

Mobile 2

```
<input id="mobile2" name="mobile2" class="small" size="12" type="text" onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey
                || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false)
                || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
                || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9)
                || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40)
                || (event.keyCode==46) )"
                class="medium"  onKeyPress="return numbersonly(event, false)" onKeyDown="limitText(this.form.mobile2,this.form,10);"
```

onKeyUp="limitText(this.form.mobile2,this.form,10);" maxlength="10"/>

The Div Element I wish to animate:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div id="slider">
```

hello world
    < / div>

Thats about it.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly something like:

```
$('#secondInput').keyup(
    function(){
        if ($('#firstInput').val() == $('#secondInput').val()) {
            $('#slider').animate({/* slide into view */}, 500);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. That looks kinda like it would work, the keyup will trigger the slider on success wont it, not slide each time a key is pressed lol

Comment: It will only animate the `$('#slider')` **if** the two inputs match. It might be worth switching [`keyup(function(){`](http://api.jQuery.com/keyup/) for `.bind('keyup','paste',function(){` though, to account for paste events.

Comment: I was gonna use -moz-user-select:none; or similar but get what you mean, will have a play. And post some code back if we get it working :)

Comment: < I really should give js a miss lol. Still cannot get this to work.

Comment: @422: if you're having problems tomorrow leave a note, here, and I'll take a look when I'm at a computer, not an iPhone =)